# Srednicki eq. (1.27): $\left\{\alpha^{j}, \alpha^{k}\right\}_{a b}=2 \delta^{j k} \delta_{a b}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, dirac-equation, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices

Srednicki, *QFT,* p. 8 writes
$$\left\{\alpha^{j}, \alpha^{k}\right\}_{a b}=2 \delta^{j k} \delta_{a b}\tag{1.27}.$$
What does exactly $ab$ here denote?

Assume I have a matrix X [0 1]
[2 3] and does a and b means the the row and the column? like for a=b=1(with a=0,1 and b=0,1) . I have $X_{ab}=3$. Is that what the author is saying?

Comment: If indices start at $0$, $X_{11}=3$ in your example. Of course, an example with $a\ne b$ is pedagogically clearer. In matrix terms, $\{\alpha^j,\,\alpha^k\}=2\delta^{jk}I$.

Comment: There isn't enough context here to answer the question. Are the $\alpha$'s fermion modes? bosons?

Comment: I am not sure what alpha here is, just some kind of matrix I guess

Comment: Yes. Here $a$ and $b$ denote row and column indices.

Comment: In the $+---$ convention, in terms of the [gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) $\alpha^i=\gamma^0\gamma^i$ so $\gamma^0=\beta,\,\gamma^i=\beta\alpha^i$ because $\beta^2=I_4$.